# How is the curve with equation $1/x^4 + 1/y^4 = 1$ called?

Tags: terminology, analytic-geometry

Well what is the graph for

$$\frac 1{x^4} + \frac 1{y^4} = 1$$
called?

According to $ Wolfram-Alpha$:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2Fx%5E4%2B1%2Fy%5E4%3D1+and+y%3Dx+and+y%3D-x

### [PLOT http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP8501gdi5621a7dbhg7c00004c68aci636bef167?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=57&w=398.&h=300.&cdf=RangeControl](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP8501gdi5621a7dbhg7c00004c68aci636bef167?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=57&w=398.&h=300.&cdf=RangeControl)

( $--$ Where the blue one is the plot for $1\over x^4 $+$1\over y^4$ = $1$ $--$ )

What is this type of graph called? (Eg: duo hyperbolas or something)

**or even the graph to**

$x^4 + y^4$ $=1$

( like the icons of iOS 7 :-) )
AS IN :

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E4%2By%5E4%3D1

[PLOT 2 http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP36911cha3ecd4675h7ci00004a14b488a8ab547c?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=33&w=296.&h=300.&cdf=RangeControl](http://www4b.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP36911cha3ecd4675h7ci00004a14b488a8ab547c?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=33&w=296.&h=300.&cdf=RangeControl)

called

Comment: Your use of the "random-graphs" tag made me chuckle :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle

Comment: Random graphs indeed!

Comment: Couldn't find any more suitable tag :-)

Comment: Images are broken...

Comment: Squircle sounds like a pokemon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms *superhyperbola* and *superellipse* are in occasional use   (and fit well with today's "supermoon" thing). From page 96 of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=YPblYyLqBM4C&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=superhyperbola%20superellipse&source=bl&ots=y_580EojUf&sig=hachjlNbvwf5K_WCVgRqnNmkkc8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GVLoU5PCI4Gj8QHFuIGYAg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Superconics are similar to conics except that trigonometric terms are raised to arbitrary power. A superellipse is 
>   $$x=a\cos^e \theta,\quad y=b\sin^e \theta$$
>   and a superhyperbola is 
>   $$x=a\sec^e \theta,\quad y=b\tan^e \theta$$

As Rahul pointed out, Wikipedia has the article [Superellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse). But no article for superhyperbola. Maybe the name triggered someone's "you must be kidding" instinct? At least, the article [Superquadrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics) mentions superhyperboloids, which are surface analogues of superhyperbola.